# Using gatling for nodejs or expressjs project?

Tags: express, load-testing, gatling

I want to use `gatling` for my `expressjs` based api. I checked there is `gatlingjs npm package` that we can use in project. When I run `./node_modules/gatlingjs/dist/index.js` as specified in tutorial at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatlingjs/v/0.0.7 I got error in commandline - `The input line is too long`.

But I am able to run gatling.bat from standalone gatling application `gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.2.0` that I downloaded separately. I checked github of gatlingjs and last update is 2 years back. Is it possible that `gatlingjs` project is discontinued? In website https://gatling.io/open-source/ it is mentioned we can use latest gatling as dependency in `maven and sbt` but package for `npm` is not mentioned. My question is should I use npm package gatlingjs (gatlingjs project last update on github 2 years back) for my expressjs api or is there some other way to use gatling.

Comment: There hasn't been a commit on that project for more than two years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle` v3.2.0 in my project instead of using `gatlingjs` npm package as `gatlingjs` npm package updated 2 years back it is best to use `gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle` v3.2.0 as it is latest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the module `gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle` you've mentioned does not exist on **npmjs.com**. Instead I can find the maven repository with the same name here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling.highcharts/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle/3.6.0

Would you let me know the npm module destination?

[Screenshot from npmjs.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjlNf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Huge misunderstanging. gatling and gatlingjs, despite having similar names, are completely unrelated.

Gatling is a load testing tool that runs on the JVM where tests are written in Java. It can of course be used to load test a nodejs application, serve-side HTTP technology is irrelevant.

gatlinjs is something else.